# Implementing expensive c++ iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

suppose we have class like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A{
    struct it{
        it(int i) : i(i){
            printf("c-tor %d\n", i);
        }

        it &operator++(){
            i++;
            return *this;
        }

        int operator*(){
            return i;
        }

        bool operator!=(const it &ot){
            return i != ot.i;
        }

        int i;
    };

    it begin() const{
        return it(0);
    }

    it end() const{
        return it(10);
    }

    it end_it = it(10);

    const it &xend() const{
        return end_it;
    }

};

int main(){
    A a;

    printf("for\n");
    for(A::it i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
        printf("%d\n", *i);


    printf("c++11 for\n");
    for(int j : a)
        printf("%d\n", j);


    printf("memoize\n");
    A::it my_end = a.end();

    for(A::it i = a.begin(); i != my_end; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", *i);


    printf("ref\n");
    for(A::it i = a.begin(); i != a.xend(); ++i)
        printf("%d\n", *i);
}
```

EDIT: the iterator is const iterator. In the example is very simple and this is not obvious.

When we do first for loop, new end iterator is constructed for each loop iteration.

If we assign the class from end() to a variable (e.g. memoize), there are no such problem.

The C++11 for probably doing exactly the same.

Finally, `end()` may return reference, but code is much more complex and probably will make problems in the future.

What is correct way to implement expensive iterator?

Comment: If you don't modify the container, you may want to call `end()` only once before entering the loop. See also [Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects/)

Comment: yes, this is const iterator, I'll edit the question.

Comment: The constness of the iterator has little to do if you modify the container (and not the contents of the container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Herb Sutter's GotW on [temporary objects](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects/). He suggests you can call `end()` only once before entering the loop, avoiding a call to `end()` for every iteration.

However, he suggests to measure whether the iterator temporary creation is a performance bottleneck (it may be very quick or even optimized by the compiler, for example) as to avoid *premature optimization*.

> ***Definition***: **Premature optimization** is when you make code more complex in the name of efficiency without data that it’s actually needed.